# Difference between 'resultingly' and 'as a result'

Tags: word-choice

Dictionaries tell me that they are the same, but I was always suggested to avoid using "resultingly". Why?

Comment: I wonder why this happens. Is "resultingly" a newly created word?

Comment: An [Ngram comparing the 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+a+result%2C+resultingly&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cas%20a%20result%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bas%20a%20result%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAs%20a%20result%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cresultingly%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bresultingly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BResultingly%3B%2Cc0) seems to show that "resultingly" has little usage. It was even marked as incorrect by this site's word checker (wavy red underlines).  It's in the dictionaries, but is not treated very seriously.